# Update null values by value in same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table in MS SQL Server, where are some null values in column "value"

```
Group   ID    Value
A       1     10
A       2     
A       3     
A       4     40
B       1     
B       2     20
B       3     30
B       4
```

I want to update null values by not null in the same group with with the first higher ID, or if there is not any higher in same group, first lower. So the result should look like this.

```
Group   ID    Value
A       1     10
A       2     40
A       3     40
A       4     40
B       1     20
B       2     20
B       3     30
B       4     30
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use windowed version of `SUM` function in order to determine islands of `NULL` valued records along with the record having the higher ID in the same group:

```
SELECT [Group], ID, Value, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID DESC) AS grp
FROM mytable
```

**Output:**

```
Group   ID  Value   grp
-----------------------
A       4   40      1
A       3   30      2
A       2   NULL    2
A       1   NULL    2
B       4   40      1
B       3   NULL    1
B       2   20      2
B       1   10      3
```

You can now wrap the above query in a `CTE` and use another `CTE` to do the update:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Group], ID, Value, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID DESC) AS grp
FROM mytable
), ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT [Group], ID, Value,  
          MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group], grp) AS group_value  
   FROM CTE
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Value = group_value
WHERE Value IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5acb/1)

**Edit:**

The above query doesn't handle the edge case where the *very last* record within a `Group` slice is `NULL`. To handle this case as well you can use the following query:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Group], ID, Value, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID DESC) AS grp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID) AS grp2
FROM mytable
), ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT [Group], ID, Value,            
          MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group], grp) AS group_value,  
          MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group], grp2) AS group_value2  
   FROM CTE
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Value = COALESCE(group_value, group_value2)
WHERE Value IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e086/1)

Answer (score 5):

Please try this-

**DATA GENERATION**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    GroupCd CHAR(1),
    Id INT,
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('A',1,10),
('A',2,NULL),
('A',3,NULL),
('A',4,40),
('B',1,NULL),
('B',2,20),
('B',3,30),
('B',4,NULL)
```

**SOLUTION**

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Value = b.Value
FROM @T a
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT a.GroupCd,a.Id,Coalesce(a.Value,z.Value,z1.Value) Value 
    FROM @T a
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Value
        FROM @T b
        WHERE a.GroupCd = b.GroupCd
        AND b.Value IS NOT NULL AND a.Id < b.Id
        ORDER BY Id 
    )z
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Value
        FROM @T b
        WHERE a.GroupCd = b.GroupCd
        AND b.Value IS NOT NULL AND a.Id > b.Id
        ORDER BY Id DESC
    )z1
)b ON a.GroupCd = b.GroupCd AND a.Id = b.Id

SELECT * FROM @T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
GroupCd Id          Value
------- ----------- -----------
A       1           10
A       2           40
A       3           40
A       4           40
B       1           20
B       2           20
B       3           30
B       4           30

(8 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can try This simple Method

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    GroupCd CHAR(1),
    Id INT,
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('A',1,NULL),
('A',2,NULL),
('A',3,30),
('A',4,40),
('B',1,10),
('B',2,20),
('B',3,NULL),
('B',4,40)

SELECT
    *,
    NewVal = COALESCE(Value,(SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM @T WHERE GroupCd = T.GroupCd AND Id > T.Id AND Value IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Id ASC))
    FROM @T T
```

My Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
update MY_TABLE set [value] = [newValue] from (
    select [Group] [newGroup],
           [Value] [newValue]
    from (
        select [Group], [Value],
               row_number() over (partition by [group] order by [Id] desc) [rn]
       from MY_TABLE
       where [Value] is not null
    ) [a] where [rn] = 1
) where [Group] = [newGroup] and [Value] is null
```

Comment: The inner query will select just the record having the biggest `Id` value within each `Group` partition. This may be a `NULL` value, or a not relevant value, since a `NOT NULL` record can immediately follow this record.

Comment: It is still wrong. Try executing the `UPDATE` against the sample data provided.